# Error 404 in Yii about urlManager not accepting string as id

Tags: url, yii

What would be the correct rule in the `urlManager` in order for it to accept string ids? It shows *Error 404 on actionView. Url: /sampleSite/index.php/transaction/I201303001*.

This is how my `urlManager` looks like:

```
        'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>true,
        'rules'=>array(

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'                     =>'<controller>/view',  
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'    =>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:>'       =>'<controller>/<action>', 
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'             =>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
    ),
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try using regExp to accept any string (including numbers)

```
'rules'=>array(

        '<controller:\w+>/<id:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>'                     =>'<controller>/view',  
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'    =>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:>'       =>'<controller>/<action>', 
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'             =>'<controller>/<action>',

    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'rules'=>array(
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>'                     =>'<module>/<controller>/view',  
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'    =>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'             =>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>'                     =>'<module:\w+>/<controller>/view',  
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'    =>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'             =>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
```

Comment: I already tried that one before. It works but the other modules returns "Error 404: The requested page does not exist." Any other ideas?